# Raspberry Pi PICAN issues copying pre-compiled kernel image

Tags: linux, debian, raspberry-pi

I recently purchased a PICAN CAN-Bus Board for Raspberry Pi. I am new to linux and am having issues copying over the pre-compiled kernel image. These are the instruction it says to follow (below).

The quickest way to try this board out is to use pre-compiled kernel image. 
Download the image from http://lnxpps.de/rpie/ and copy over to your Pi.

```
# cp can-test/kernel.img /boot
# cp -a can-test /home/pi
```

I have downloaded the pre-compiled kernel image to a USB thumb drive. Plugged it into my raspberry pi. Shows up mounted /media/USB DISK. How do I get terminal to point to the USB drive and copy over theses files?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
cp /media/USB\ DISK/can-test/kernel.img /boot
cp -a /media/USB\ DISK/can-test /home/pi
```